# Export Sketchup file to SVG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg, export, sketchup

I am currently running Sketchup Make Version 17.1.173 (I assume this is a free version as I have never handed money over) I am trying to export to svg (or pdf, ps, eps and vector format basically).

I tried to install an extension from flightofideas as linked [here](http://sketchucation.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=323&t=62530)

I can right click on my model and now have Export to SVG file in the dialog menu. But I cannot seem to export anything. The dialog remains open and does not generate a file. (I tried opening the Ruby console in case this would reveal an issue, but its empty).

Is this possible with my current setup? 
I am worried I am missing some step to prepare the model before attempting to export.

I also tried printing the file to pdf, but when I open that in AI I get an embedded bitmap.

I am running MAC OS High Sierra. 
Adobe Illustrator CS6.
Sketchup Make Version 17.1.173.

(I have very rudimentary knowledge of Sketchup).

Right click dialog

[image: Dialog]

SVG Export dialog

[image]

Comment: Oh, I also thought I might be able to convert it online here:   https://cloudconvert.com/ but there is no support for skp files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the SketchUp drawings, as 2D vector graphics, in [EPS](https://fileinfo.com/extension/eps) file format.

EPS can include both vectors and bitmap images. EPS vectors however does not support gradients, so if you have a drawing with gradients your best choice is to export it as PNG or TIFF then trace it to vector in Illustrator and save as SVG.

I also tried, in SketchUp, the flightofideas plugin to save as SVG, but it didn't work.

As answer to your comment: I have SketchUp Make version 17.2.2555 and EPS is one of the export options.

Comment: I dont seem to have eps as an export option in my version. Only jpg, png and tiff. Maybe I need to download a newer version (I hope it' available in the free version). Thank you for trying the svg exporter.

Comment: Thanks again, it seems the modern free version is online only. I downloaded Pro version and exported to eps, but I guess I only have 30 days to use Pro version. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can download SketchUp Make from [Softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Graphic-Editors/Google-SketchUp.shtml). Click on Download and then choose the right version (x64 17.2.2555)